# 4 Questions in proof of Theorem 2.9 of Unit 5 of Hungerford Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Note : unfortunately, I a single theorem, I have 4 questions. So, I will award a bounty of 50 points to anyone who answer all 4 questions.

While studying Galois Theory from Thomas Hungerford , I have 2 questions in Lemma 2.9 on page 248.

It's image:
[image]

[image]

Line in which I have questions are underlined.

> (1) How did author deduced that such a system always have a non- trivial solution? The matrix in (1) must have Linearly independent rows, but why that matrix must be Linearly Independent?

> How does in 2nd underlined line author deduced that $\sigma a_{2} \neq a_{2} $?

Edit : Unfortunately, there are 2 more questions in the same proof
:

> In the line just above (2) I am unable to deduce why Linear Independence of $u_{i}$ over J' implies that there exists some $a_{i} $ not in J'?

> How does author deduced $\sigma a_{1} , \sigma a_{r} , 0,0,0...$ is a solution of (2)?
> It's my humble request to guide me on these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A homogeneous system with more unknowns than equations always has infinitely many solutions. This is obvious by doing row reduction, or alternatively by noting that an $n\times( n+1)$ matrix has rank at most $n$, and thus it has nontrivial kernel.

As for $\sigma a_2\ne a_2$, I think the explanation on page 249 is fairly clear: since $u_1,\ldots,u_r$ are linearly independent in $J'$, if $a_1u_1+\cdots+a_ru_r=0$ with $a_1,\ldots,a_r\in J'$, we would have that $a_i=0$ for some $i$. But $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ are assumed nonzero, so at least one of them, say $a_2$, fails to be in $J'$. This means that there exists $\sigma\in J$ with $\sigma a_2\ne a_2$.

The system $(2)$ is the system $(1)$ with $\sigma$ applied to each equation. If $a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1}$ solves $(1)$, then $\sigma a_1.\ldots,\sigma a_{n+1}$ solves $(2)$.

Comment: can you please look at the post again as I have added it and it will be very kind of you if you consider answer it completely.